# what's wrong in my xml code? I want to make a TextInputLayout but can't

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

what's wrong in my xml code? I want to make a TextInputLayout but can't. can you help what should i do to make TExtInputLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:Layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:Layout_marginBot="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:Layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.widget.support.design.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match parent"
            android:layout_heigth="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ouuu"
            android:id="@+id/etnama"
            android:hint"nama anda">

       </android.widget.support.designt.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the **design support library** to use the `TextInputLayout` you 
 have to add the `TextInputEditText`.
Something like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/etnama"
         ...>

     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

With **androidx** libraries you have to add the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) and use:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...>

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```